# Advanced Java File I/O tutorials? Tips? Advice?

Tags: java, database, file, frameworks, io

I'm working on a project right now that will make use of Java File I/O that goes beyond the simple "write this string to a file" documentation and tutorials that I find on the net.  This project will essentially provide a database mechanism, similar to the popular "NoSQL" databases that are gaining a lot of press these days.  However, I'm unable to find a ton of documentation that provides detailed information on which APIs to use, how to use them, etc.  I've also been looking for any generally accepted design patterns around Java File I/O, but without any luck.

If I had to list a couple of requirements, I'd say:

- Pseudo-transactional support (not a hard requirement, as it can be implemented higher up in the API stack)
- Ability to write data of an arbitrary length in a structure that can be read back later on
- Indexing
- Ability to remove an object from the "database" efficiently
- Fast searching
- Possible multi-threaded access (multiple read threads, single write, most likely)

Can anyone point me to any tutorials, documentation, design patterns, etc. that may be helpful?  Are there any open source frameworks that revolve around Java File I/O?  I know of a lot of frameworks that provide wrappers around NIO for the purposes of Network I/O, but nothing File-related.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Apache Commons Transaction](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/file/index.html). It supports transactional file access, by performing the work in temporary files, and committing the work by moving them to the actual files.

You might also be interested in the [XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) project, although I haven't pored through it's sources.

As far as searching is concerned, the Apache [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/) projects would be of help.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd never heard of XADisk, but it looks intriguing.  I knew of Apache Commons Transaction, which is why I wasn't overly concerned with how support for transactions would be implemented.

Comment: It seems that support for transactions will have to be built in first. Search and other capabilities can be built on top of the API or within the API, depending on whether you want such operations to be transactional as well. In other words, if you need to get away with dirty reads, non-repeatable reads and phantom reads, will have to ensure that search and other read related operations will also have to be performed in the context of a transaction. Understanding how JTA works, goes a long way in designing a transactional API.