# Wrting Objects to a file and searching through them in an Android App

Tags: java, android, database, file-io

I want to create an android that allows the user to enter data, like name and id number. I want to save that data as an object, to a file. I know I can do that using ObjectOutputStream, which I did, and it works. However, I also want the user to come back later, be able to add more entries to the same file, and search through his/her previous entries. I know that only RandomAccessFile has that capability, but I still want to write objects since it's easier to deal with.

Does anyone have any tips on what's the best way to approach this?

I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246703/advanced-java-file-i-o-tutorials-tips-advice), but I am not sure if I can use the libraries mentioned there on android. I was also looking at SQLite, but I have no experience with it and I am not sure if it's the right option for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with SQLite. Otherwise you will have to add database-like search index features to your object serialization logic (if you need a search feature). But if you want to stick with your current approach, how about writing each object into a separate file with a serial number? That way you can directly open a specific file by number and you don't need to seek around in a single file.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll look into both methods. Thank you!

Comment: Just updating: SQLite is working wonders! Thanks!